# Why do we say הנותן ליעף כח with Hashem's Name?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shacharis-morning-prayer, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

The Rema rules in OC 225:2:

> יש אומרים מי שנעשה בנו בר מצוה יברך בא"י אמ"ה שפטרני מעונשו של זה וטוב לברך בלא שם ומלכות
>
> Some say that one whose son becomes a Bar Mitzvah should make a blessing of "Blessed are You, Hashem, our G-d, King of the world, Who exempted me from the punishment of this one." It is good to make the blessing without Hashem's Name or kingship.

Mishnah Berurah ad. loc. §8 explains:

> משום שלא הוזכרה ברכה זו בגמרא
>
> Because this blessing was not mentioned in the Gemara.

Yet in OC 46:6, the Shulchan Aruch and Rema write:

> יש נוהגין לברך הנותן ליעף כח ואין דבריהם נראים: הגה אך מנהג פשוט בבני אשכנזים לאומרה
>
> Some have the custom to make the blessing of "Who gives strength to the weary," but their words do not appear correct. Rema: But the prevalent custom among Ashkenazim is to say it.

And the Mishnah Berurah there writes (§22):

> ר"ל בהזכרת שם ומלכות
>
> That is to say, with a mention of Hashem's Name and kingship

This latter blessing isn't mentioned in the Gemara, either. Why do we make this blessing with Hashem's Name yet omit it by a Bar Mitzvah?

Comment: You can't ask a Kasha on a Mayseh. We can list dozens more blessings not in the Talmud and half are still said and half aren't and half are still disputed. Lighting Shabbat candles, lighting Yom Tov candles, lighting Yom Kippur candles, Dam Betulim, Mattir Asurim, Magbiah Shefalim, Somekh Nofelim, SheAsani Kirtzono, Pidyon HaBen conclusion, HaMelekh BiKhvodo at Maariv, Mekaddesh Et Shimcha BaRabbim, Barukh SheAmar, Oseh HaShalom, Borei Nefashot, Modim Derabanan, I'm getting tired of listing,

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think that Hamelech bichvodo and Mekadesh et Shimcha barabbim are the best examples, since they're lightning rods for this discussion, whereas the others are either said or not, without a continued discussion (oversimplified, I know)

Comment: @DoubleAA Then perhaps the question should be phrased the other way - since we have so many Berachos which aren’t in the Gemara which we still preface with Shem U’Malchus, why is Baruch Sheptarani the outlier?

Comment: I would say this is an established minhag every day and this is a rare once in the child's lifetime beracha, so the minhag didn't become sufficiently established. This theory brakes down in many of daa's examples, though.